# Find 10 most repeated elements in a vector in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I'm suppose to find `10` most repeated elements in a vector with `n` elements,

(the elements are from `1-100`)

does anyone know how to do that?

I know how to find the one that is most repeated element in a vector but I don't know how to find 10 most repeated elements with `n` being unknown.

Comment: Are the numbers sorted, i.e. `[1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 ...]` or random in the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `unique` for that case. In my example, I have 4 numbers and I want to grep the 2 with the most occurances.

```
A = [1 1 3 3 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4];
B = sort(A); % Required for the usage of unique below

[~,i1] = unique(B,'first');
[val,i2] = unique(B,'last');
[~,pos] = sort(i2-i1,'descend');
val(pos(1:2))

    1 3
```

Replace `val(pos(1:2))` by `val(pos(1:10))` in your case to get the 10 most values. The get the number of elements you can use `i1` and `i2`.

```
num = i2-i1+1;
num(1:2)

ans =

     7     3
```

Comment: thanks this helped alot but do u know how i can than find how many times each of the top 10 appears in the vector?

Comment: See edit or the answer from @Karmtal (hist is giving you the number).

Answer (score 5):

```
a = randi(10,1,100);
y = hist(a,1:max(a));
[~,ind] = sort(y,'descend');
out = ind(1:10);
```

for number of occurrences use `y(ind(1:10))`.

I had some doubts so I tested it many times, it seems to work.

Comment: Very nice. However, you can use `hist(a,unique(a));`, reducing memory requirement.

Comment: @Nemesis, I thinks `hist(a,unique(a));` won't work. I even changed `length(a)` to `max(a)` it made problems when `max(a) > length(a)`

Comment: using `unqiue` did work for me, but I didn't try it with your array. So maybe you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already know how to find the most repeated element, you could use the following algorithm:

1. Find the most repeated element of the vector
2. Remove the most repeated element from the vector
3. Repeat the process on the new vector to find the 2nd most repeated element
4. Continue until you have the 10 most repeated elements

The code would look something like:

```
count = 0;
values = [];
while count < 10
   r = Mode(Vector);
   values = [values r]; % store most repeated values
   Vector = Vector(find(Vector~=r));
   count = count + 1;
end
```

Not efficient, but it'll get the job done